# how i can compute the average number of games played by year?

Tags: r

In my data set i have column 'Game' it's represented the games played , So i wanna calculate average number of game by year .

this is my data set .

```
playerNBA <- data.frame(
  playerID =c("abercda01" , "addybo01", "allisar01" ,
              "allisdo01" , "ansonca01" , "armstbo01")

  ,yearID =c(1871 , 1871 , 1872 ,
             1873 , 1873 , 1874 )

  ,stint =c(1 , 1 , 1,
            1 , 1 , 1)

  ,teamID =c("TRO" , "RC1" , "CL1" ,
             "WS3" , "RC1" , "FW1")

  ,lgID  = c(NA , NA , NA , NA , NA , NA)

  ,Game = c( 1 , 25 , 29 , 27 , 25 , 12 ))
```

i tried many times  but all of the code i wrote it was wrong

```
playerNBA[median(playerNBA$G),]
```

Answer (score 2):

[dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) is going to be your best friend here. The code below will group your rows by year and then using summarise, you can calculate the mean on your newly formed groups.

```r
library(dplyr)

playerNBA %>% 
  group_by(yearID) %>%
  summarise(avgGames = mean(Game))
```